# Regex to find the last word in string -Javascript flavor

Tags: regex

I am close but no quite there.  I am trying to match the last word to pull out the last name.

My Regex:

Insured Name:\W*(?<insured_last_name>.*)

Text that I am searching:

Insured Name:

FRED & ETHYL MERTZ

Sample here...
https://regex101.com/r/McdMcq/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match `Insured Name:` until the end of the line. Then match a newline and optional following whitespace chars.

Then at the line where you want to get the last word, first match until the end of the line, then backtrack until the last space, and capture 1+ non whitespace chars in group `insured_last_name`

```
\bInsured Name:.*\r?\n\s*.* (?<insured_last_name>\S+)
```

In parts

- `\bInsured Name:` Match literally
- `.*\r?\n\s*` Match the rest of the line, a newline and 0+ whitespace chars
- `.*`  Match the rest of the line and match the last space
- `(?<insured_last_name>\S+)` Match 1+ non whitespace chars in group `insured_last_name`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V5ClHa/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `/\w+$/gm`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/McdMcq/4

Explanation:

- `\w`: Look for alphanumeric letters
- `+`: At least one
- `$`: And then the end of the string

If there are multiple rows and potentially garbage data in between I would recommend you to remove the 2 newlines (`\n\n`) and then do a Positive Lookbehind looking for "Name". Demo: https://regex101.com/r/McdMcq/5

If you need to store the result in a capture group simply enclose `\w+$` with parenthesis and group name (i.e `(?<insured_last_name>\w+$)`) on any of the two regexes.

Comment: How can I keep the capture group and do this?

Comment: There is alot of data above and below.  For some reason your example is not working on my original data??

Comment: When i copy and paste original data into your example it doesn't work, although it looks like the exact same format.  I don't understand why.

Comment: When designing regex it is important to take use a big chunk of data. Can you update the original  regex101 with more data?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to define your data set a little more, but you can try

```
Insured Name:\n+.*(?<insured_last_name>\b.+)
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/NiakXf/2)

It starts at "Insured Name:", then any empty lines, then will read the following line until the final word boundary (excluding the EOL); anything after that is in your named group.